# Is there any evidence that correcting a learner's oral mistakes in class has a negative impact?

Tags: reference-request, teaching-methods

In a [comment](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/4011/is-there-a-scientific-evidence-of-class-teacher-importance-for-adult-learners?noredirect=1#comment4882_4011) on the question [Is there a scientific evidence of class / teacher importance for adult learners?](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/4011/) Gavenkoa makes the following claim:

> There is evidence that certain teaching activities has negative impact on exam scores. One of such thing is correction of oral mistakes.

I find that hard to believe. It is one thing to say that something has no noticeable impact (see [Effectiveness of reformulating incorrect sentences as feedback?](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/2483/)), but it is a very different thing to say that such teacher interventions may have a *negative* effect.

Which studies have shown that correcting a learner's oral mistakes in class has a negative impact?

Comment: I'm sorry. My mistake, the article http://epi.sc.edu/ar/AS_4_files/Truscott%202007.pdf  is about writing skills: *The conclusions are that, based on existing research: (a) the best estimate is that correction has a small negative effect on learners’ ability to write accurately, and (b) we can be 95% confident that if it has any actual benefits, they are very small*.